# modifying part of a list in place using list comprehensions in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like

```
test = ['A','B','C','D D','E E','F F']
```

I would like test to become the following (that is, the spaces removed)

```
test = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF']
```

I used a list comprehension in Python to achieve this:

```
>>> [re.sub(' ','',i) for i in test]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF']
```

My question is - what if I explicitly DO NOT want `re.sub(' ','',i)` to run on the first three elements of my list? I only want the `re.sub` function to run on 'DD','EE', and 'FF'.

Is this way efficient? I understand a list comprehension takes up memory because Python makes a copy.

```
test2[3:] = [re.sub(' ','',i) for i in test[3:]]
```

Or should I just loop through the values of test that I want to modify like this:

```
for i in range(3,len(test)):
    print i
    test[i] = re.sub(' ','',test[i])
```

Comment: Do you care if it's efficient? How long is your list? What matters more for this bit of code, efficiency or maintainability? Have you measured it?

Comment: If you know that only the last three will have spaces in them, then the last list comprehension is the way to go.

Comment: @nmichaels I do care if it's efficient, my list is really long. I just know that under no circumstances do I want the first 3 values to ever be touched...but everything after the 3rd value needs to be checked for spaces.

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't know if only the last 3 will have spaces - I just know I don't want to touch the first three elements.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it sounds like you're optimizing prematurely.

Secondly, you can express your requirements with a single list comprehension:

```
In [5]: test = ['A','B','C','D D','E E','F F']

In [6]: [t if i < 3 else re.sub(' ', '', t) for (i, t) in enumerate(test)]
Out[6]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF']
```

Finally, my advice would be to focus on correctness first, then on readability. Once you've achieved those, profile the code to see where the bottlenecks are, and only then optimize for performance.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't think about this. I probably am optimizing prematurely, but just wondering if I had a really long list, whether looping is preferred over a list comprehension because list comprehension makes a copy of my data.

Answer (score 2):

The best of `re.sub`, `str.replace` and `str.translate` is the `str.replace`. So, use **str.replace**

Here is a little timing comparison.

```
import re

def test1():
    test = ['A','B','C','D D','E E','F F']
    test[3:] = [re.sub(' ','',i) for i in test[3:]]

def test2():
    test = ['A','B','C','D D','E E','F F']
    test[3:] = [i.replace(" ", "") for i in test[3:]]

def test3():
    test = ['A','B','C','D D','E E','F F']
    test[3:] = [item.translate(None, " ") for item in test[3:]]

from timeit import timeit
print timeit("test1()", "from __main__ import test1")
print timeit("test2()", "from __main__ import test2")
print timeit("test3()", "from __main__ import test3")
```

**Output on my machine**

```
3.96201109886
0.985305070877
1.11600804329
```

**Note:** As @roippi mentioned in the comments, `str.translate` will not work in this form in Python 3.x. So, ignore that in the race, if you are using Python 3.x

Comment: I'll note that this doesn't work in python 3; they removed the `removechars` functionality entirely. (I don't know why)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is - what if I explicitly DO NOT want re.sub(' ','',i) to
>   run on the first three elements of my list?

Okay, answering that question first:

You can use `enumerate` and a conditional expression to specify the behavior you want for i < 3 and i >= 3:

```
[x if i<3 else re.sub(' ','',x) for i,x in enumerate(test)]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF']
```

Note that this simple `sub` operation can be handled more straightforwardly by `str.replace`.

(I will leave out discussion of whether this sort of optimization is worthwhile, other than saying the time saved by not doing `re.sub` on the first three elements is miniscule)